# Is it possible to tell iCloud Drive to ignore certain files and certain patterns?

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, icloud

I want some sort of a `.gitignore` equivalent to iCloud Drive, where I can tell it to ignore certain files and patterns like `node_modules` or some `large_document.pdf` that I don't necessarily want to sync. I feel like I should be able to do this since I'm paying for storage and I only want to pay for what I actually want backed up.

Comment: It's possible if you use a third-party iCloud client.

Comment: Do you mind suggesting one? I would rather exclude certain files than put all the files I want inside some special folder

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/261437/28517